# How to avoid wrapping PHP result into another array?

Tags: javascript, php

The following is the php code:

```html
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["loggedUser"])) {
    generateAndProvideData($_SESSION["loggedUser"]);
} else {
  //error handling
}

function generateAndProvideData($loggedUser) {
    $connection = establishConnectionToDatabase();
    $UserData   = retrieveUserData($connection, $loggedUser);
    echo json_encode($UserData);
}

function retrieveUserData($connection, $loggedUser) {
    return $connection->query("
        SELECT name, vorname, email
        FROM benutzer
        WHERE id = '".$loggedUser."'
    ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function establishConnectionToDatabase() {
    try {
       $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=------------','------','-----');
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $connection;
 }
 ?>
```

On the scriptside, it was called like this:

```js
function populateUserData() {
  $.post('../include/getUserDataForBenutzerprofil.php', {
    //nothing to transmit
  }).then((data) => {
    data = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log("data from getUserDataForBenutzerprofil.php is ", data)
    //$('#name').val(data.name)
  })
}
```

Now, as far as I understand php, it creates an array with the names of the columns being the keys to the respective values.
However, the array that is returned to the front-end seems to be multidimensional, see the following output:

> [{"name":"----","vorname":"-----","email":"---.---@example.de"}]

Why is that? And is there any way around it?
This way, I always have to address the numerical index "0" first, and then in the second index write out the respective associative key. While this isn't a major issue, it feels rather "unclean", since this is neither necessary nor was it intended.

Comment: so what's your problem? use `$.each(data,function(key,value){ .....});` to iterate over it and do whatever you want to do

Comment: the "problem" is that Id rather see the result being a one-dimensional array. I can of course coax it into a one-dimensional array afterwards, but if there is any way to prevent it from being injected into another array, then I would rather chose this way.

Comment: data returned from a query will be always a multi-dimensional array if more than one record will be there. so you can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

`When using the JSON.parse() on a JSON derived from an array, the method will return a JavaScript array, instead of a JavaScript object.`

and

`As long as the response from the server is written in JSON format, you can parse the string into a JavaScript object.`

so try changing your response format to `json`.

```
function populateUserData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../include/getUserDataForBenutzerprofil.php",
        // data: {},
        dataType: "json" //<-- this
    }).then((data) => {
        data = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log("data from getUserDataForBenutzerprofil.php is ", data)    
    })
}
```

Assuming the response is a valid JSON string of course.

Comment: This didn't really help, the data returned is then automatically parse from JSON to a JS Object, so I dont need to use JSON.parse() on the scriptside anymore. However, it is still inside a multidimensional array, where the first dimension is redundant.

Comment: @JSONBUG123 What *exactly* are you receiving in the raw response data? Is it only `{...}`?

Comment: When Im using your suggested approach, then I get a syntax error since JSON.parse() parses an Object. If I remove it and output the "raw" response data, then I get an already finished object:

data from getUserDataForBenutzerprofil.php is  
(1) […]
​
0: {…}
​​
email: "-----.-----@example.de"
​​
name: "-----"
​​
vorname: "------"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []

Comment: That's not a valid JSON string. Either works with the array that you have now, as in JSON.parse(data)[0] or change the return format to "json" as I suggested and you'll get what you're asking for, but the response data **has to be** a valid JSON format.

Comment: Quite frankly you're better off working with the JSON Array that you're getting.

Comment: As I said, when I'm using your approach I get back an already finished Object, not a string. This Object is the same as it would be if I used my approach and then parsed the string via JSON.parse().

Comment: @JSONBUG123 you should be getting an `Object` in both scenarios, one should be an Array and the other in the second approach a pure object as in `{}` but that requires the response to already be exactly that. If it's not exactly that, then don't set the dataType to "json" and work with the Array object you're getting. Sorry it's really hard to understand without seeing what's going on.

Comment: Also for the third time: Check if you're receiving a valid JSON string - https://jsonlint.com/ since you mentioned that `When Im using your suggested approach, then I get a syntax error`